# Differentiate $y = 2^x + 2^{-x}$

Tags: implicit-differentiation

I have a question about negative powers in implicit differentiation.

I was asked to differentiate the equation

$$y = 2^x + 2^{-x}$$

**Now, from previous studies, I can prove the following:**

$y = a^x$

$\ln y = \ln a^x = x \ln a$

$\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = \ln a$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = y \ln a = a^x \ln a$

**hence differentiating $y = a^x$ results as $\frac{dy}{dx} = a^x \ln a$.**

Using the above information, I attempted to differentiate the equation above via implicit differentiation:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2^x \ln 2 + 2^{-x} \ln 2$$

However, apparently, my solution is incorrect. 
Instead, it is

$$\frac{dy}{dx} = 2^x \ln 2 - 2^{-x} \ln 2$$

I'm confused.
Why is my solution wrong?

Comment: Chain rule.$ $$ $

Comment: just start with $y=a^{-x}$, you get $\frac{dy}{dx}=-a^{-x}\ln a$

Comment: use the chain rule, alternatively: the division rule: $(2^{-x})'=(\frac{1}{2^x})'$

Comment: @MANMAID I see, I got it thanks. I'll answer the question myself.

Comment: Just follow the same method you did for $a^x$ substituting $x$ by $-x$. Then you can see you get $-x\ln a$ in the second step.

Comment: @Smurf see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$y = a^{-x}$

$\ln y = \ln a^{-x} = -x \ln a$

$\frac{1}{y} \frac{dy}{dx} = -\ln a$

$\frac{dy}{dx} =- y \ln a = -a^{-x} \ln a$

**hence when differentiating $y = a^{-x}$ results as $\frac{dy}{dx} = -a^{-x} \ln a$.**

credit - @MANMAID, @smurf

Comment: Your negative sign is in the wrong place.

Comment: Still wrong. Did you check your first two lines or not?

Comment: @user21820 ok now it must be fixed.

Comment: Right. Great work! Just note that you must always check that you don't divide by zero. Here $y$ is always positive, but in other situations you may get possible division by zero, and must avoid it. And you can mark your own answer as accepted, if you wish.

Answer (score 3):

You can differentiate $2^{-x}$ in two ways (at least).

You can use the chain rule. This rule, roughly speaking, says that the derivative of $f(g(x))$ is $g'(x)f'(g(x))$. To apply this rule to $2^{-x}$ let $f(x)=2^x$ and $g(x)=-x$. Then $f(g(x))=2^{-x}$ and the derivative is $g'(x)f'(g(x))=-1\cdot\ln 2\cdot 2^{g(x)}=-\ln2\cdot 2^{-x}$.

The other way is as follows. Write $2^{-x}=\left(\frac12\right)^x$. Then, its derivative is $\ln(1/2)\left(\frac12\right)^x=-\ln 2\cdot 2^{-x}$.

Actually, there are other ways, including implicit differentiation and differentiaitng $1/2^x$ as a quotient of functions. But I think that they are more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=-x,$ so that $y = 2^{-x} = 2^u.$

The **chain rule** tells you that
$$
\frac d {dx} 2^{-x} = \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac {dy}{du}\cdot\frac{du}{dx} = \left( \frac d {du} 2^u\right) \cdot \frac d {dx} (-x) = \cdots\cdots.
$$